# Translate code to DIRECTX directxmath

Tags: c++, directxmath

How can i translate the code to directxmath code?

```
// Create a quaternion that rotates about the world up
 Quaternion quatYaw = CreateFromAxisAngle( Vector3(0,1,0), yaw )
 // Transform the camera offset and up by this quaternion
 offset = Transform( offset, quatYaw)
```

Do i use XMQuaternionRotationAxis for CreateFromAxisAngle?
And also, what function do i use for: Transform

I need to use functions from DIRECTXMATH
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/directxmath/

Answer (score 2):

> Do I use XMQuaternionRotationAxis for CreateFromAxisAngle?

Yes.

> What function do I use for: Transform

You use [XMVector3Rotate](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/directxmath/nf-directxmath-xmvector3rotate).

You can find these matches just by comparing the function signatures, or plugging "DirectXMath rotate vector by quaternion" into a search engine (this was on the first page of results)..

Comment: This page on [Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dxmath/pg-xnamath-migration-d3dx) has a complete table of D3DXMath to DirectXMath conversions.